# Can I extend Flume sink to make it write different data to multiple channels?

Tags: java, flume

A follow-up question to [my previous question about Flume data flows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21481034/how-do-i-transform-events-in-flume-and-send-them-to-another-channel/21488032)

I want to process events and send extracted data further. I'd like to accept big sized events, like zipped html > 5KB, parse them and put many slim messages, like urls found in pages, to another channel, and also some page metrics to yet another one. Since parsing pages is resource consuming, I'd rather not replicate messages to different processors for these tasks, both of which require parsing html and building DOM in memory. Also, if possible, I'd like to avoid sending serialized DOM from parser to metrics calculators. Can I extend a sink and for every incoming events spawn multiple events to multiple outgoing channels? Something like

```
                 htmlChannel                urlChannel
HtmlPagesSource -------------> PageParser -------------> UrlConsumer
                    html            |          urls
                                    |
                                    | metricsChannel 
                                    -------------------> MetricsConsumer
                                         metrics
```